# 'Close' option is not available when program minimized to the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, vb6, taskbar

I am programming VB6 in Win7. I have a program with a borderless window, no caption, no icon, no control box, etc. just a window. Using a command button, I can minimize the window to the Task Bar, and from there return it back.

My problem is, when minimized to the Task Bar, I right-click on the icon, and I wish to close the program from there. Win7 won't let me close the program via the pop-up menu. The close option is on the menu, but it does nothing.

How can I close this program from the task bar menu?

Comment: Do you have any logic in the QueryUnload or Unload events?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in VB6 Forms subsystem -- when form's `BorderStyle` is set to none `Close` menu on the taskbar and `Alt+F4` shortcut as well just stop working as there is no system menu on the form.

Unfortunately a workaround involves subclassing and here is one way to deal with the issue:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND             As Long = &H112
Private Const SC_CLOSE                  As Long = &HF060&

Private m_pSubclass As IUnknown

Private Property Get pvAddressOfSubclassProc() As Form1 '-- change Form1 to current form name
    Set pvAddressOfSubclassProc = InitAddressOfMethod(Me, 5)
End Property

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set m_pSubclass = InitSubclassingThunk(hWnd, Me, pvAddressOfSubclassProc.SubclassProc(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
End Sub

Public Function SubclassProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long, Handled As Boolean) As Long
    Select Case wMsg
    Case WM_SYSCOMMAND
        If wParam = SC_CLOSE Then
            Unload Me
            Handled = True
        End If
    End Select
End Function
```

This will need `mdModernSubclassing.bas` from [Moderen Subclassing Thunk repository](https://github.com/wqweto/ModernSubclassingThunk) added to your project for the IDE-safe subclassing implementation.

Comment: This subclassing method feels a bit overkill for this little project and for my humble standards of hobby programming. But I am grateful for this answer, so I start to think about more simpler solutions to this problem, maybe just change the window interface.